# Want to compare 2 csv files to get count of updated, new and deleted records

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose we have one file `abc.csv.dat`

```
100000114,AU79 Attract Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,100000113,AU79 Attract Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
100000115,AU79 Sauve Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,100000112,AU79 Sauve Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
100000117,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,100000116,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
100000119,DU AU79 Bandit Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,100000118,DU AU79 Bandit Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
```

Second file is `xyz.csv.dat`

```
100000114,AU79 Attract Mens Deo 250 Ml Can,100000113,AU79 Attract Mens Deo 250 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
100000115,AU79 Sauve Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,100000112,AU79 Sauve Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
100000119,DU AU79 Bandit Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,100000118,DU AU79 Bandit Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
100000120,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 350 Ml Can,100000116,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 350 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
```

I want to compare these two files using unix commands to create my unix shell scripts which will count the new rows, updated rows and deleted rows.
My sample files are small but the actual files are containing 20,000+ records.

Thanks for ur attention.

Comment: How can you tell whether two record have changed? Is there a primary key?

Comment: See in first file we hav 4 records and after some logic the new file gets created xyz.csv.dat.We have PK as first column.

Comment: in first file we hav updated 1st row with some new values keeping first column fixed.2nd row is same.3rd row we hav de;eted and 4th row is same.new record is added in this new file 100000120,.....Now I want to count these rows which i hav deleted,added and updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) to get most of what you want. It treats "update" as "delete and insert".

insertions: `comm -13 abc.csv.dat xyz.csv.dat`
deletions: `comm -23 abc.csv.dat xyz.csv.dat`
unchanged: `comm -12 abc.csv.dat xyz.csv.dat`

comm requires the input files to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more in-depth example using comm:

```
$ comm -3 <(sort abc.csv.dat) <(sort xyz.csv.dat) | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | awk -F , '{if (a[$1]) {print "^"$1","} {a[$1] = $0}}' > data2.txt
```

--count updated rows:

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -E -f - xyz.csv.dat | wc -l
1
```

--count deleted rows:

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -v -E -f - <(comm -2 -3 <(sort abc.csv.dat) <(sort xyz.csv.dat)) | wc -l
1
```

--count new rows:

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -v -E -f - <(comm -1 -3 <(sort abc.csv.dat) <(sort xyz.csv.dat)) | wc -l
1
```

--list the update rows:

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -E -f - xyz.csv.dat
100000114,AU79 Attract Mens Deo 250 Ml Can,100000113,AU79 Attract Mens Deo 250 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
```

--list the delete rows:

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -v -E -f - <(comm -2 -3 <(sort abc.csv.dat) <(sort xyz.csv.dat))
100000117,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,100000116,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 150 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
```

--list the new rows:

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -v -E -f - <(comm -1 -3 <(sort abc.csv.dat) <(sort xyz.csv.dat))
100000120,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 350 Ml Can,100000116,AU79 Altitude Mens Deo 350 Ml Can,18,_,18,Deo
```